# Using URL Rewrite to change part of URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use an URL Rewrite on an IIS 8.0 to rewrite existing URL:s on a developer machine. The reason for this is that I don't want to change existing (old) code.

What I'm trying to achieve is to change the following code in the response stream:

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com/path/page.asp?a=1">Foo Page</a>
```

into:

```
<a href="http://www.foo.localhost/path/page.asp?a=1">Foo Page</a>
```

But when I'm trying, I end up with:

```
<a href="foo.localhost">Foo Page</a>
```

And as you all know, this is not a very satisfying result.

**So - how do I do this rewrite proper to achieve what I'm trying to do?**

I know there are better ways of doing this, using application variables etc., but it's an old solution and I don't want to mess too much with the application itself. I want to keep the changes to a minimum. At least to begin with.

The rules I tried look like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="foo.com" enabled="true">
        <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="foo.com" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="foo.localhost" />
      </rule>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I guess there is some regex magic I should be using.

Comment: Well, the URL Rewrite module won't change the links your write in your code, it can only redirect or rewrite the requested url.

Comment: I edited the question to include what I've done. To be specific, it is an outbound rule, so yes - it does rewrite the links I write in the code.

Comment: Woo, what to say...I feel a bit ashamed...anyway, if you change your pattern to `foo.com(.*)$` and in the action the value to `http://foo.localhost{R:1}` you will probably start to get something better.

Comment: No need to feel ashamed - the fault is all mine for not being totally clear to begin with.

Comment: And thanks for the push in the right direction. You solved it for me. The complete answer seems to be to use `(.*)$foo.com(.*)$` for pattern and `{R:1}foo.localhost{R:2}` for action value.

Comment: Oh yes, right. I didn't notice you wanted to keep the beginning as well (not too smart tonigt :D). So to do it the "clean" way you should change the pattern to `^(.*)foo.com(.*)$`.

Comment: Works like a charm. I wouldn't do this in a production environment, though, since I guess you'll take a performance hit. Write me a formal answer and I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Parsing all the returned HTML and replace the content matching a regex in the selected elements is probably resources consuming... I will post an answer in the next few minutes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rule needs to be changed to:

```
<rule name="foo.com" enabled="true">
  <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^(.*)foo.com(.*)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}foo.localhost{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

In the pattern, `^(.*)` will match anything (0 or more characters) from the beginning before `foo.com` and `(.*)$` anything after `foo.com` until the end.

You can then use the back references in the `action`, where `{R:1}` will take the value matching `(.*)` before `foo.com` and `{R:2}` the value matching `(.*)` after `foo.com`

Comment: Oh thank you :D finally after all these years, I know what means these {R:1} {R:2} !!! p.s. also works for wildcard pattern syntax, like: <match url="*potato*">